# inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)

Tags: permissions, kde, fstab

With the latest update of KDE, I am seeing these errors:

```
Sep 26 23:07:30 desktop sddm-greeter[709]: inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
Sep 26 23:08:18 desktop kdeinit5[819]: inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
Sep 26 23:08:19 desktop kgpg[878]: Error loading text-to-speech plug-in "flite"
Sep 26 23:08:19 desktop org_kde_powerdevil[897]: inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
Sep 26 23:08:23 desktop plasmashell[856]: inotify_add_watch(/etc/fstab) failed: (Permission denied)
```

My `/etc/fstab` permissions are:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 7182 Jun 26 21:51 /etc/fstab
```

Is that not correct?

Comment: You're right, it's not correct unless you run kde as user root

Comment: `chmod o+r /etc/fstab` seems to have resolved it, but further testing may be needed. I would also prefer not to have that file readable by everyone.

Comment: Why don't you want /etc/fstab to be world readable? It is by default on all mainstream distros, and a lot of things assume that it is. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/575564/does-etc-fstab-need-to-be-world-readable

Comment: @JosephSible - OK, I'll leave it world readable then. Seems like a minor security hole to me, but if that's the design I'll go with it.

Comment: How is it a security hole? Do you have sensitive information in it?

Comment: @JosephSible all users can see mount points and mounting details. Even if credentials are stored elsewhere that information itself is a minor weakness in my opinion.

Comment: If the mount points are actually mounted, that's moot, as all of the /proc/*/mounts files contain basically the same info.

Comment: @JosephSible in my particular case, the mount points would not be mounted unless an admin user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not correct. `/etc/fstab` is supposed to be world readable. **A LOT** of programs depend on this, and it's world readable on every standard Linux distribution. You're not supposed to put credentials or anything else that's actually sensitive in this file (see [Does /etc/fstab need to be world readable?](https://serverfault.com/q/575564/402194) for how to avoid this), and hiding anything else in it would just be security-through-obscurity, which isn't actually secure at all.